# GVFS SMB Browse amd NT1

Tags: samba, smb, gvfs

When browsing on my network and clicking a specific ubuntu server set up as a samba server on my network in attempt to show the share listing, I get the error "Failed to retrieve listing from the server: invalid argument". After researching this, I have discovered this is due to the fact the ubuntu server defaults to use SMB2 as the server min client version and for some reason GVFS SMB Browse defaults to using NT1 when trying to display a share listing. I confirmed this by changing the server min version to NT1 on my server and it indeed worked. Has anyone found a way to display the share listing of a samba server (via GVFS) without having to changing the server min version to NT1? I am quite surprised that this does not appear to have been fixed in GVFS given the fact that Microsoft has deprecated SMB1 for a little while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. It's still a bug: [gvfs can't list shares from smb servers that disabled SMB1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107)

The only way around this is to ask for the server AND it's share explicitly which bypasses the gvfsd-smb-browse bug.

Either like this in the Linux client file manager: `smb://hostname.local/sharename` or as a mount.cifs mount.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its a shame really, I love Linux but when there are bugs such as these which have not yet been fixed it makes promoting Linux to Windows users rather difficult. Being able to browse the network is just more convenient for the average home user as they may not necessarily know the name of every server and share in the network and I don't have this problem on Windows at all. I should not have to re-enabled SMB1 just for this functionality, given its security flaws. Thanks again.